# What is the geometric difference between partial derivative and ordinary derivative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Ordinary derivative of a function let $~y=f(x)~$ represents the slope of the tangent drawn at the point $~x~$ to the curve $~f(x)~$. But, what about partial derivative ? Please, attach images if possible for understanding.

Comment: partial derivative is for a function of several variables

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I want to know the geometric meaning of partial derivative.

Comment: it's the slope of the tangent line when other variables are kept constant; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative)

Comment: You might find [my YouTube lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pt2t71U2kU4&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=22&t=0s) helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial derivative gives us the slope of tangent line to a surface at a cross-section.

> $~\frac{∂}{∂x}f(x,y)~$ means the rate at which $~f(x,y)~$ will change with respect to $~x~$ if $~y~$ is kept constant.
>
> i.e.,  if you take a cross section of the surface through a specific value of $~y~$ then you will get the slope of the tangent to the surface at that cross section. This slope varies as $~x~$ varies. If you move one unit along the $~x$-direction at a cross section, then you will also move $~\frac{∂f}{∂x}~$units along $~z$-axis.

Similarly, $~\frac{∂}{∂y}f(x,y)~$ means the rate at which $~f(x,y)~$ will change with respect to $~y~$ if $~x~$ is kept constant.

For **example**, in figure 114.7, $~y~$ is held constant at $~y = b~$ and the red curve describes the curve $~x = f(x,b)~$ on the surface. The value of $~\frac{∂}{∂x}f(x,y)~$ is the slope of the tangent line to the curve at the point $~x = a~$ and $~y = b~$. Similarly for $~\frac{∂}{∂y}f(x,y)~$.

[image]

(http://www.tectechnicsclassroom.tectechnics.com/s7p5a51/geometric-interpretation-of-partial-derivatives.php)

Comment: Thanks. I went through Quora, but the image attached with the answer written by the writer confused me. But, your attached image solved my issue. Thanks again. 

Comment: You are welcome @RajatDash

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question. This only explains what the partial derivative is; however, the question concerns something else (in addition to the partial derivative). The question also concerns the regular derivative, and asks what the difference between the two is.

Comment: Read the question (body) carefully. @allyourcode